# Sorting XML tag values into separate files using python?

Tags: python, xml, file, sorting

This is an example of what the XML code looks like:

```
<root>
<user1><Read>7</Read><Click>0.33</Click></user1>
<user2><Read>2</Read><Click>0.95</Click></user2>
<user3><Read>7</Read><Click>0.12</Click></user3>
</root>
```

How would I use python to sort all of the users with "Read" value 7 into one file and all the users with "Read" value 2 into another.

The two new files should be something like this: 
The file with all the read 7's in it:

```
<user1><Read>7</Read><Click>0.33</Click></user1>
<user3><Read>7</Read><Click>0.12</Click></user3>
```

The file with all the read 2's in it:

```
<user2><Read>2</Read><Click>0.95</Click></user2>
```

I do not care about the `<root>` tag being there in the new files, I just care about sorting the users.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please search for a solution to this broad question and make an earnest attempt. Then, come back with issues.

Comment: @planet260 import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("user_list.xml")

container = tree.find("user")

data = []
for elem in container:
    key = elem.findtext("Read")
    data.append((key, elem))

data.sort()

container[:] = [item[-1] for item in data]

tree.write("new-data.xml")

Comment: @planet260 but it says " File "users.py", line 13, in <module>
    data.sort()
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' and 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'"

Comment: @Ina21, please edit your question and show us the code and the error messages there in a well-formatted way.

Comment: Please do not post code and error message in comments but [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58185180/edit) original post.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to group and sort or rather, for Python's itertools.groupby you first need to sort:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import itertools

xml = '''<root>
<user1><Read>7</Read><Click>0.33</Click></user1>
<user2><Read>2</Read><Click>0.95</Click></user2>
<user3><Read>7</Read><Click>0.12</Click></user3>
</root>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)

def keyf(el):
  return el.find('Read').text


for key, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(root, key=keyf), key = keyf):
    with open(f'file{key}.xml', 'w') as f:
        for el in group:
            f.write(ET.tostring(el, encoding='unicode'))
```

Note that I have used the suffix `.xml` for the output files but if you write out several top level elements like above in the case that you have several elements with the same key value then the result file is technically not well-formed XML.

Comment: FYI - with your proposed answer, there's no reason to use the third-party module `lxml` but Python's built-in [`xml.etree`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) unless of course you are running your top skills: `xslt` and `xpath`!

Comment: @Parfait, you are right but as the built-in API is a bit different to write to a file I think or at least I don't know both APIs well enough to spell the code out I went with the lxml API where I currently have a better handling on the output/serialization ways. I need to look at the xml.etree API to see how the `ET.tostring` can be done there. I might add it later or perhaps if you know it off the top of your head feel free to edit and provide the alternative code path.

Comment: Simply replace your `lxml` import line with `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`.

Comment: @Parfait, fine, somehow I thought I would need some more convoluted serialization approach for the `xml.etree` than the `tostring` method, but as I said, I just don't have enough experience with the API.